# How to pass data from u-boot bootloader to QNX application via ram?

Tags: u-boot, qnx

Using QNX 6.5.x with u-boot as a bootloader, on an ATSAMA5d3x module.

We'd like to pass some amount of data, ~1.5kb, from the bootloader into QNX via RAM, rather than trying to pass it via flash storage.

Is there a mechanism to tell QNX to reserve an area of RAM and not touch it? This would let us mmap it from the QNX application to read the data out of it, without QNX using it for heap or otherwise zeroing it out.

Is there another approach you've used to pass data like this into QNX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QNX startup-* programs permit the use of the `-r` argument to reserve a block of phyiscal address space.   You can supply arguments to startup in the .build file for the bootstrap image (the source to `mkifs`).

Example:

```
[image=0x22000000]
[virtual=armle-v7,raw +compress] .bootstrap = {
    # reserve 4k at paddr 0x20000000 and don't clear it
    startup-atsama5d3x-ek -vvv -r 0x20000000,4096,1
    # reset of boot code goes here
}
[+script] .script = {
    # and so on
}
# and so forth
```

Ref: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/s/startup_options.html

Comment: and this memory would be expected to be mappable via mmap() or or mmap_device_memory()?

Comment: Correct.  `mmap_device_memory()` maps an arbitrary range of physical addresses to your process' address space, no questions asked.   This does of course require the  PROCMGR_AID_MEM_PHYS privilege; if you're not doing this for the direct benefit of driver code that already needs IO mapping privileges, you might want to write a small, easy-to-validate application to perform the read securely.   At the limit `dd if=/dev/mem of=/run/info_dump seek=<offset/block_size>` works in a pinch in startup scripts as root.

Answer (score 0):

I try using qnx 6.5.0 on ATSAMA5d3x
I use default  nand driver from bsp, but periodically(when try open some bin file) i get this error:

fs-etfs-sama5d3x: readcluster DATAERR on cluster xxxxxx

after reset all ok, i can run binary, but after a while this error will appear again

Why is this happening? You use default driver?
Maybe you know something

*Forgive me for asking in your question, too little information on qnx 6.5.0 on ATSAMA5d3x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j3kB.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32176376)

Comment: the qnx nand driver I believe only has single bit hamming correction. This isn't sufficient for use on nand devices. If you can confirm and want to have further discussions just email me, chmorgan@gmail.com and we can chat about how we resolved it.